# Laravel get data based on relationship

Tags: php, laravel

So i have two tables, Bids table and Projects table. Relationship between them as such:

Bids.php:

```
public function projects()
  {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Projects');
  }
```

Projects.php:

```
public function bids()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Bids');
}
```

This is
[Projects table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdUu7.jpg). This is [Bids table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vn0jG.jpg). I want to print all the bid data along with their respective projects data in each row of table in View.
I tried to do this way in my controller:

```
$bids= auth()->user()->bids()->get();
   foreach($bids as $bid)
   {
        $projects= Projects::find($bid->project_id);
   }
    return view('bids.index',compact('bids','projects'));
```

index view:

```
 @if($bids->count() != 0)
           @foreach($bids as $bid)                      
            <tr>
            <td><a href="{{ route('projects.select',$projects->id) }}">{{$projects->name}}</a></td>
             <td>{{$bid->status}}</td>
             </tr> 
             @endforeach
                                
             @else
             <tr>
             <td colspan="6" class="text-center">No record found.</td>
             </tr>
             @endif
```

But I got the data repeated in one row of table. So what should be the proper way to do it? Sorry if this is a bit vague, but this is my best way to explain it in abstract.

Comment: so what is currently blocking your from doing that? not knowing how to access the relationship from the Bid model?

Comment: @lagbox hi i edited my question, please check :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the relationship you defined here.

```
$bids = auth()->user()->bids()->with('project')->get();
```

This will eager load the `project` relationship for each Bid.

I really don't know how you want this to look in the view but you can iterate the bids and get the project information pretty simply:

```
@foreach ($bids as $bid)
    {{ $bid->id }}
    {{ $bid->project->name ?? '' }}
@endforeach
```

Side note:

Your `Projects` model should be `Project`, models are named in the singular and the database tables are named in the plural. Your relationship should be `project` not `projects` since it is a singular relationship, belongs to; it can only return a single record or `null`.

Comment: hi i've just realised i misplaced my <tr> outside of my foreach loop. I did as you told, I can displays {{$bid->status}} but the {{$bid->projects->name ??'' }} displays nothing in the view.

Comment: you should make the name changes because the `belongsTo` relationship can not match up the records correctly because it thinks your foreign key is `projects_id` not `project_id` because of how you named the relationship

Comment: Thank you for the help! I changed the model name and now i works perfectly! Now that I knew the reason why my relationship is always not working!